# How to index and change a value within a matrix using a variable?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

For example, I have a variable `i` and I want to set `i=(2,3)` such that `B(i)=B(2,3)=7`.

```
B=[1 2 3 4
    5 6 7 8];
i=('2,3');
B(i)
```

I am kind of stuck here. Please help.

Comment: `i=[2 3]` then `B(i(1),i(2))`

Comment: Thank you Sardar!

Comment: Please also see [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)